# HDFS: recoverLease succeeds but file is still locked

Tags: loops, hadoop, append, hdfs, ksh

Friends,

My hadoop version is 2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1133.

I keep getting the following error when i try to append to a file on HDFS:

```
appendToFile: Failed to APPEND_FILE <file> for     DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1270257846_1 on <ip_address> because this file lease is     currently owned by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1054975138_1 on <ip_address>
```

When i run a "recoverLease" command on the same file with 10 retries, i get the message that it SUCCEEDED

```
hdfs debug recoverLease -path <file> -retries 10
recoverLease returned false.
Retrying in 5000 ms...
Retry #1
recoverLease SUCCEEDED on <file>
```

I'm running my append in a loop in a ksh script; this error appears only after the first append happens. What am i doing wrong?